# Getting error when finding Checkbox id android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to find a checkbox by id in this line:

```
rememberMeCheckbox = findViewById(R.id.remember_me_checkbox_id);
```

After running code the app is not responding when I use this line. Otherwise, it works fine.

**My code**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private EditText inputPhoneNumber, inputPassword;
    private Button loginButton;
    private CheckBox rememberMeCheckbox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        inputPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.login_phone_number_input);
        inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password_input);

        rememberMeCheckbox = findViewById(R.id.remember_me_checkbox_id);
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<com.rey.material.widget.CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/remember_me_checkbox_id"
    style="@style/Material.Drawable.CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Remember me" />
```

Comment: Can You add logcat?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I think it might be the wrong import. I copy and pasted Your code and it works.
Change this line:

```
private CheckBox rememberMeCheckbox;
```

To this:

```
private com.rey.material.widget.CheckBox rememberMeCheckbox;
```

Or just import:

```
import com.rey.material.widget.CheckBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

why you not use the Checkbox from androidx ?

if u use from default library maybe is easiest